# PlaceHolders and Persistent Dynamic Controls (ADVANCED)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate, placeholder, multiview

**Warning! This problem is not for the feint of heart. I've spent several days in all trying to troubleshoot it.**

I have a `Wizard` control with about 5 steps, each with several controls ranging from very simple to very complex such as custom jQuery combo boxes based on `DropDownList`s and `TextBox`es. Each step has several of the controls wrapped in a `PlaceHolder` control.

The `Wizard` along with all `PlaceHolder`s and their child `Controls` are nested inside of a `View` of a `MultiView`. On the same page I have another `View` styled like a Form, but not one. This view has corresponding `PlaceHolder`s for each of `PlaceHolder`s within each step of the `Wizard`.

Depending on the ReferralUrl I call the following function to "Toggle" the view from the `Wizard` to the form style view by moving all the controls, then setting the active view as follows:

```vb
Protected Sub ToggleView() Handles ViewToggle.Click
    If Wizard_mv.ActiveViewIndex = 0 Then
        ViewToggle.Text = "Toggle Wizard View"
        fPH1.Controls.Add(wPH1)
        fPH2.Controls.Add(wPH2)
        fPH3.Controls.Add(wPH3)
        fPH4.Controls.Add(wPH4)
        fPH5.Controls.Add(wPH5)
        Wizard_mv.ActiveViewIndex = 1
    ElseIf Wizard_mv.ActiveViewIndex = 1 Then
        ViewToggle.Text = "Toggle Form View"
        wPH1.Controls.Add(fPH1)
        wPH2.Controls.Add(fPH2)
        wPH3.Controls.Add(fPH3)
        wPH4.Controls.Add(fPH4)
        wPH5.Controls.Add(fPH5)
        Wizard_mv.ActiveViewIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Immediately after this, I use another function for pre-filling the controls with values from a record in a database. After allowing the users to make some changes, they may resubmit the updated record to the database. The problem is that this works just fine if I do so from the `Wizard` but not after toggling. The trace shows that the `Control Tree` is empty at the time of submitting the updated record, and hence I cannot grab the user-entered/pre-filled values from this view. **The pre-filling works great and the "Selected" values are all correct. The problem arises on the PostBack after clicking submit and it loses all the values and controls.**

**Please do not answer unless** you fully understand my problem and are willing to help. I think the problem very well lies within the page lifecycle. Mysteriously, when I submit from my Wizard, on the postback in Page_Init I get my control values loaded, however when I submit from my form view, neither the controls nor their values are loaded. From what I read, this is an issue of persistence. Really hoping there's a relatively easy solution for this.

Here's a sample of my markup in my `Wizard` (all styling removed for brevity):

```html
<asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Product Info">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wPH1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        <asp:Table ID="ProductInfoTable" runat="server" Width="100%">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell><h3>Product Line</h3></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell><h3>Publication Type</h3></asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell><h3>Request Type</h3></asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <div class="ui-widget">
                        <!-- Autocomplete Combobox -->
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="productLine_ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="productLineSDS" ViewStateMode="Enabled" DataTextField="Product" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="productLine_cb" runat="server" EnableViewState="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        <button id="productLine_btn" type="button" title="Show All Items"></button>
                    </div>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="docType_ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="docTypeSDS" DataTextField="DocType" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="requestType_ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="requestTypeSDS" DataTextField="RequestType" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                    <asp:MultiView ID="Attachment_mv" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
                        <!-- File Upload/Browsing Display -->
                        <asp:View ID="AttachmentUploadView" runat="server">
                            <h3 class="inlineH">Attach File: </h3>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="AttachmentFile_btn" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Button ID="UploadFile_btn" runat="server" Text="Upload File" />
                        </asp:View>
                        <!-- File Attached Display -->
                        <asp:View ID="FileAttachedView" runat="server">
                            <h3 class="inlineH">Uploaded File: </h3>
                            <asp:Label ID="FileAttachedLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Literal ID="FilesOnServer" runat="server" />
                        </asp:View>
                    </asp:MultiView>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:WizardStep>
```

My Page Lifecycle Events, as requested (in chronological order for your convenience) :)

```vb
Dim referrerPage As String
'Initialize Dynamic controls here. These are controls that need to be prefilled, etc.
Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    'DO NOT PREFILL at this stage, as the Controls are not yet rendered and will cause errors.
    '  Use this section for detecting the "referrerPage" and missing "id" parameters when expected, etc.
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ViewState.Clear()
    End If

    Try
        referrerPage = Right(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath, Len(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath) - Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.LastIndexOf("/"c) - 1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session.Item("referrerPage")) Then
            referrerPage = Session.Item("referrerPage")
        End If
    End Try

    If StrComp(referrerPage, "wizard.aspx") <> 0 And String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session.Item("referrerPage")) Then 'Initialize Session state to remember "referrerPage"
        Session.Add("referrerPage", referrerPage)
    End If
    If StrComp(referrerPage, "formdetails.aspx") = 0 Then
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params("id")) Then
            'This line checks for an expected "id" param value and if none exists, forwards the page back to "tcom.aspx"
            Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath)
        Else
            ToggleView()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'Prefill Dynamic controls here.
Private Sub Page_PreLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreLoad
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        productLine_ddl.DataBind()
        docType_ddl.DataBind()
        requestType_ddl.DataBind()
        '...and several more DataBinds for each individual
        '   control in the wizard. Nothing more.
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        'Benign code for querying the database to get User info for Page.User.Identity.Name
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        'Here is completely benign code for hiding a couple controls.
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_PreRenderComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
    'PREFILL HERE when appropriate. This occurs after checking the "referrerPage" and ensuring a value for the "id" parameter.
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Try
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params("id")) Then
                PrefillWizard(Request.Params("id"))
            Else : output.Text += "Source: " + Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

To anyone who can help with this, you have my eternal gratitude. ;)

Comment: What part of the page lifecycle are you generating the controls in?

Comment: @Felan: Within the `Wizard` all controls are declared statically in the markup, then moved to the form-like view if the referral url is correct. I identify the referrer, url params, and Toggle the view in Page_Init, DataBind the controls in Page_PreLoad, and prefill the controls in Page_PreRenderComplete. ;)

Comment: As you said, your life cycle events are probably the issue, can you post that code, also do you have any if(!Postback) code anywhere?

Comment: @rickschott: As requested bud... and lol at whoever downvoted this question. Apparently they can't read, as I have put a ton of research into this problem and a lot of effort into asking it. :P I gave fair warning that this is a big question. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the control tree of the page must be exactly the same during every postback. That means that you have to add **all the control every time** no mater which `ActiveViewIndex` is set. Preferably in `CreateChildControls` or page init. In the `ToggleView` function you can than set the visibility of the controls.

Comment: I actually FINALLY found a solution. I'm not sure if what you're saying is the same, so let me ask. I discovered that my ToggleView was not actually triggering before the submit on the postback so in fact the controls were not even loaded, i.e. the `ActiveViewIndex` was not correct anymore. My solution was to add a url parameter (can be done with a Session variable too) to check during the Page_Init whether or not the previous state was indeed my form based view and if so, to RE-TOGGLE it prior to doing my update. This ensured that the controls were populated first. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Not really. If you add the controls dynamically when the users changes view. The viewstate wont be preserved when the view is changed again. Add the control all the time in CreateChildControls, than databind/set visibility on them when View is changed.

Comment: I'll go ahead and choose your answer, but if you don't mind I would appreciate if you could expound on the `CreateChildControls` a bit more. This is a new concept to me. Thanks ;)